# Software recommendations

Tags: discussion

Can I ask questions about software application recommendations anywhere in the stackexchange system?

For example, I have a requirement, which will involve software and hardware.  I want to type this requirement up somewhere where possible readers will be able to recommend hardware and software solutions to my requirements?

Comment: No. See [Q&A is hard, let's go shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping)

Comment: You could visit the chat room for SuperUser or ServerFault and ask there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of question is what we call [shopping questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

They are not, in general, appropriate to Stack Exchange sites, for the reasons outlined in the blog post linked above.

Note that the post includes a **how to ask** such questions so they **are OK**.

Comment: Thanks, but not to sure how to convert "I need a hardware/software solution/off the shelf package which can count and recognise employees as they walk into and out of the building, and update a local database automatically" into a "how to ask" question?

Comment: Then Stack Exchange might not be the place for your question.

Comment: Would it be worth creating such a site on stack exchange, where answers simply point the questioner to companies who already provide such ready made solutions?

Comment: @oshirowanen - That's not what Stack Exchange does. Look at http://slant.co - that's a site purpose built for such questions.

Comment: Or maybe https://www.quora.com/.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Software Recommendations Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44877/software-recommendations) that has not yet been created. You could follow that and keep an eye out for when it becomes active.

Comment: Based on the title alone, I get the feeling that is just for software recommendations, I am basically after an area where I can get full solution recommendations, i.e. ready make solutions/company recommendations etc.

Comment: Ahh I see. Then that may not be exactly what you are looking for then

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] is an already graduated site.